# SAML SSO for Bluemix App (Liberty for Java)

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml-2.0

I have been having trouble getting a SSO service on Bluemix to work for an existing app on Bluemix that I have inherited.

The app previously had the older version of SSO working which came into action when a user selected an admin link to sign in as an administrator. But this obviously stopped working when the new version of SSO arrived. So I set up the new SSO service for the app, boarded the tool with the SSO provisioner tool, and configured and binded the SSO service to my Bluemix app.

It now looks like this is working - I get the Open ID sign in page, but then it goes no further and does not move onto the landing page/URL that is set up in the service.

Is there any further coding on the application that needs to take place? Looking at any of the docs in Bluemix it says there is no furhter coding needed for Liberty for Java apps....but I'm not so sure...

Any help with getting this to work correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

What Identity Provider do you use? This tutorial might help- http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/security/library/se-bluemix-secure-apps-single-sign-on/se-bluemix-secure-apps-single-sign-on-pdf.pdf